# Why would one want to use <aside> on a sidebar?

Tags: html

I have been reading a tutorial on semantic HTML. For the `<aside>` tag is mentions that a sidebar would be a good candidate. For example:

```
<aside class='sidebar'>
  <h2>Sidebar</h2>
  <p>Some sidebar content</p>
  <nav>
    <h3>HTML &amp; CSS Tutorial</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>Introduction</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Basic Web Pages</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>etc...</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <nav>
    <h3>JavaScript Tutorial</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>Introduction</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Hello, JavaScript</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>etc...</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</aside>
```

Why would one want to hide the sidebar from the HTML outline? Wouldn't this also hide the nested element such as `<nav>` and make them useless?

Comment: How would we know the mind of the author of whatever tutorial you're reading?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have seen a lot of people debating on the use of the `<aside>` tag, and yes many of those say they use it for navigation.

This is your case, based on the code provided, however I think the *meaning* the author intended may be different than what we understand.

In summary, the `<aside>` tag should be used to represent content that is indirectly related to the main content of the page, these can be quotes, links to related content, etc. However, many people refer to navigation sections as *sidebars*, and thus people think that's the intended use for the aside tag.

HTML5 main point is *semantics*, if you want to make a navigation section, be it a sidebar, topbar, bottombar, floating bar, whatever, you should be using a `<nav>` tag, not an `<aside>`.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/aside):

> The HTML  element represents a portion of a document whose
>   content is only indirectly related to the document's main content.
>   Asides are frequently presented as sidebars or call-out boxes.

Just note that on that quote, "sidebars" doesn't really mean *navigation bar*; **BUT** also not that if you have links that are *indirectly* related to the content of the page, you can group those inside a `nav` tag, contained inside an `aside` tag, like:

```
<aside>
   <nav>
      links here
   </nav>
</aside>
```

> The element can be used for typographical effects like pull quotes or
>   sidebars, for advertising, **for groups of nav elements**, and for other
>   content that is considered **separate from the main content of the page**.

[Source](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-aside-element.html)

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for the detailed answer!